# cannot resolve method 'getwindow()' in Activity

Tags: java, android

am trying to add this this line in my Activity   `builder.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);`

but I find find this error Cannot resolve method'getwindow'

as am trying to add my code like this

```
        NewGuestCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TabsActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Insert Table Name");
                // Set up the input
                final EditText input = new EditText(TabsActivity.this);
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(input, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
// Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                builder.setView(input);
                // Set up the buttons
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        final String Table_Name = input.getText().toString();
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TabsActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Insert number of Covers");
                        // Set up the input
                        final EditText input2 = new EditText(TabsActivity.this);
// Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
                        input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                        builder.setView(input2);
                        // Set up the buttons
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                String Cover_check = input2.getText().toString();
                                TablesFragment.Check_Items = ConnectionClass.Ret_dt("Select * From ChecksItems Where Check_ID = 0");
                                if (!TablesFragment.Check_Items.containsKey("Change_Temp")) {
                                    if (TablesFragment.Check_Items.size() > 0) {
                                        ArrayList<Object> Valrows = new ArrayList<Object>();
                                        if (TablesFragment.Check_Items.get("Item_ID").size() > 0) {
                                            for (int i = 0; i < TablesFragment.Check_Items.get("Item_ID").size(); i++) {
                                                Valrows.add("");
                                            }
                                        }
                                        TablesFragment.Check_Items.put("Change_Temp", Valrows);
                                    }
                                }
                                if (Integer.parseInt(Cover_check) > 0) {
                                    String st = ConnectionClass.Ret_Col("Select  Max (CheckSerail) AS Ser From Checks_V where Officer = 0 AND OutLet_ID = " + ConnectionClass.OutletID + " And Rest_ID_Active = " + ConnectionClass.Rest_ID);
                                    if (st.trim() == "")
                                        st = "0";
                                    int Check_Serial = Integer.parseInt(st) + 1;
                                    long Check_ID = Long.parseLong(ConnectionClass.SelectNewIDCheck());
                                    st = "insert into Checks .......
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

                        builder.show();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
                builder.show();
```

as I need from this method that when the alert dialog start the keyboard starts automatically that I don't need to touch the edit text to show the key board
sorry if any thing is not clear and sorry for my bad english
I hope this case could be solved

by the way activity looks

```
public class TabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Answer (score 0):

call getWindow() by giving any views reference.ex

```
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: thanks for your help but I still have the error here

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8537518/5956451). You need to call `getWindow()` on the `Dialog` Class.